# Can't import matplotlib

Tags: python, installation, numpy, matplotlib

I installed matplotlib using the Mac disk image installer for MacOS 10.5 and Python 2.5. I installed numpy then tried to import matplotlib but got this error: `ImportError: numpy 1.1 or later is required; you have 2.0.0.dev8462`. It seems to that version 2.0.0.dev8462 would be later than version 1.1 but I am guessing that matplotlib got confused with the ".dev8462" in the version. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Numpy 2.0 is not backward compatible with matplotlib, and it *will* crash if you try to run matplotlib on top of it. If you want to run numpy 2.*, you will need to rebuild every package which uses numpy C API (matplotlib, scipy, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the troublesome code located in `Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py` in my python distribution on Windows

```
nn = numpy.__version__.split('.')
if not (int(nn[0]) >= 1 and int(nn[1]) >= 1):
    raise ImportError(
            'numpy 1.1 or later is required; you have %s' % numpy.__version__)
```

The problem is that it is requiring both the first to digits (separated by periods) to be greater than or equal to 1 and in your case the second digit is a 2. You can get around this in a number of ways, but one way is to change the if statement to

```
if not ((int(nn[0]) >= 1 and int(nn[1]) >= 1) or int(nn[0]) >= 2):
```

or you could just change it to:

```
if not (float('.'.join(nn[2:])) >= 1.1):
```

which might be better.

Comment: +1.  But here is a simpler version: `(int(nn[0]), int(nn[1])) >= (1, 1)`.  In fact, tuples compare with the so-called "dictionary order".

Answer (score 0):

Following Justin's comment ... here is the equivalent file for Linux:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/__init__.py
```

sudo edit that to fix the troublesome line to:
if not ((int(nn[0]) >= 1 and int(nn[1]) >= 1) or int(nn[0]) >= 2):

Thanks Justin Peel!